# Reading data file with rows of variable sizes

Tags: matlab, text-processing, cell-array

I have a data file containing rows of variable sizes:

```
16 54 1 -3 5
15 5
1 9 10 5
```

How can I load it into a cell array data so that

```
data{1} = [16 54 1 -3 5]; 
data{2} = [15 5]; 
data{3} = [1 9 10 5];
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `data.txt` contains

```
16 54 1 -3 5
15 5
1 9 10 5
```

You can read it into a cell array data with the following:

```
fid = fopen('datatest.txt');
allData = textscan(fid,'%s','Delimiter','\n');
data = cellfun(@str2num, allData{1}, 'UniformOutput', false);
fclose(fid);

>> data = 

ans =    

[1x5 double]
[1x2 double]
[1x4 double]

>> data{1}

ans =

    16    54     1    -3     5
```

Comment: +1 Perfect answer I think. Also, you can add `fclose` maybe for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 2):

You can try **[`impordata`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html)** appproach that is short and concise -

```
%// Assuming filepath1 is the path to your file
data = cellfun(@str2num,importdata(filepath1,'%s'),'uni',0)
```

You can visualize the data, using **[`celldisp`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/celldisp.html)** tool that `displays contents of a cell array`, like this - `celldisp(data)`. The output would be -

```
data{1} = 
    16    54     1    -3     5

data{2} =
    15     5

data{3} = 
     1     9    10     5
```